# Do you get stamina modifier to hp at level 1?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg

When I read the 4e book cover to cover, I got the impression that at level 0 you got d4 hp + stamina modifier and then at level 1 you got your class die of hp but no stamina modifier (at level 2 you'd get it as usual).

My GM challenged this and on relook through I couldn't find what I thought I originally read.  However, all the examples I found also do not specifically say you do/don't get it so I think I just put 2+2 together myself (maybe wrongly).  It states clearly at level 0 you get stamina then at level 1 you get class die but doesn't specifically say you get stamina at level 1 that I see.

Does anyone have any example quotes one way or another?  Note, I am looking for a specific quote answer (either from the book or creators of it).  I can already see both ways so interpretations of wording I don't expect to help me.  I also am aware of what the stamina section itself says.  If providing the quotes I do know about here helps my answer please leave a comment, I can do it.

Comment: Providing quotes you know and find non-conclusive would certainly help people to not post the same quotes as conclusive answers. If you think it's too much, then maybe at least page & line numbers and two, three words why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Stamina modifies your hit points every level

From the 4th printing (page 18):

> Your Stamina modifier affects hit points (even at level 0) and Fortitude saving throws. Note that a character earns a minimum of 1 hit point **per character level** regardless of Stamina.

There would be no reason to spell out that stamina affects your hit points *even* at level 0, where you are not even part of any class yet, or that you get a minimum of 1 hit point per character level if Stamina couldn't modify your dice roll to become a negative number.

There are no exceptions to this anywhere in the rules, so your Stamina should modify your character's hit points at *all* levels.

However, this is a [question](http://www.goodman-games.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=14589) [frequently](http://goodmangames.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=15431) [asked](http://www.goodman-games.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=48155) at goodman games forums, but as users have noted there, that should have been made clear and explicitly called out in that section of the book.